# How to access parent object in recursive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

Suppose we have a tree structure like so:

- /

  - images/

    - foo.jpg
    - bar.jpg
    - day.jpg
  - vids/

    - foo.mp4
    - bar.mp4
    - day.mp4

And a representation of this structure in a JavaScript object:

```
$scope.tree = {
    title: '/',
    children: [{
        title: 'images/',
        children: [{
            title: 'foo.jpg'
        }, {
            title: 'bar.jpg'
        }, {
            title: 'day.jpg'
        }]
    }, {
        title: 'vids/',
        children: [{
            title: 'foo.mp4'
        }, {
            title: 'bar.mp4'
        }, {
            title: 'day.mp4'
        }]
    }]
};
```

Rendering the tree can be done by recursively rendering a template with `ng-include`:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree">
    <a href="#" ng-click="logNodeAndParent(child, parent)">{{ child.title }}</a>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="child in child.children" ng-include="'tree'" ng-init="parent=child">           
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="child in tree.children" ng-include="'tree'"></li>
</ul>
```

Notice that when you click a node in the tree I would like to log the child and its parent:

```
$scope.logNodeAndParent = function(node, parent) {
    console.log('Child: ' + node.title + ' Parent: ' + parent.title);        
};
```

The question is, how can I access the parent of the current child?

http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/NP7P5/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `ng-init` to set the initial parent, `tree`, then in the template, update the parent property to `$parent.$parent.child`, it should work for all levels.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree">
    <a href="#" ng-click="logNodeAndParent(child, parent)">{{ child.title }}</a>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="child in child.children" ng-include="'tree'" ng-init="parent = $parent.$parent.child">           
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="child in tree.children" ng-include="'tree'" ng-init="parent = tree"></li>
</ul>
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NP7P5/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use $parent.$parent.child instead of parent.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="logNodeAndParent(child, $parent.$parent.child)">{{ child.title }}</a>
```

Check this plunkr out:

http://jsfiddle.net/L6Vqn/6/

I believe this is because ng-repeat creates a new scope and then ng-include creates another new scope hence you have to use $parent twice.

Comment: Whilst this works for the leaf nodes it no longer works for their parents (the directories).